# Observe Firebase Analytics Event using cloud function(Firebase)

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-analytics, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cloud-messaging

In one of my iOS app I am using a cloud function that is continuously observing Firebase Events(like first_open, etc.) and we are able to observe predefined firebase events like (first_open). But when we create our own custom event(like "new_event") then observe not working.

A function that I am using for observing events :

```
exports.Test_Second_Function = functions.analytics.event('testFunction').onLog((event) => {

   

});
```

I am able to call the events from the Firebase audience with the trigger. But can we observe these events through cloud functions?
Because when I am sending this event from mobile devices then we can observe.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you provide us the code??

Comment: Thankyou but solved, will share the answer.

Comment: Please share the answer so that it helps the community.

Answer (score 0):

The solution which worked for me is that -

1. Hit a simple event(from mobile) that we want to trigger when new entries come into the audience or when the audience refreshes.
   e.g. Analytics.log("sample_event", parameters: [:])
2. This event we can check in debug view and real-time inside the Firebase Analytics section.
3. After some time entry of this event will come in event sections of the Firebase(In my case this took around 12 hours).
4. After that we just need to check "mark as conversion" from the events section(this again takes some time to reflect, In my case, this took around 8 hours).
5. Now when any user comes into our audience then this event will trigger and we can check the count also for the event(for cross check that event is called or not).

Thank you.